# Get the cumulative sum

Tags: mysql

Let's assume that I have a table in a mysql database as follows,

```
date        inQty   outQty
2011-10-24  700.00  0.0
2011-10-01  500.00  0.0
2011-10-02  500.00  0.0
2011-10-03  550.00  0.0
2011-10-04  100.00  0.0 
2011-10-05  200.00  0.0
2011-10-05  0.00    100.0
2011-10-02  0.00    500.0
2011-10-03  0.00    150.0
2011-10-24  200.00  0.0
```

and from above table I need to query following result,

```
date        inQty   outQty   Balance
2011-10-24  700.00  0.0      700.00
2011-10-01  500.00  0.0  500.00
2011-10-02  500.00  0.0  500.00
2011-10-03  550.00  0.0      550.00
2011-10-04  100.00  0.0  100.00
2011-10-05  200.00  0.0      200.00
2011-10-05  0.00    100.0    100.00
2011-10-02  0.00    500.0    0.0
2011-10-03  0.00    150.0    400.00
2011-10-24  200.00  0.0      500.00
```

how can I get this from a SQL query?

Comment: Your example does not make any sense

Comment: What is 0.0,900.00 in the first dataset? Why balance for the last row is 500? Shouldn't it be 900? Check and correct your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you're looking for a cumulative sum over a partition. This is only a guess though since your post is rather unclear since there is no clear pattern to the data. I think I understand what you're driving at though...

Perhaps you can review and edit your post to make the question clearer?

Anyway, give this a go. I don't know what your table is called so I'll post my own example.

```
create table dateCumulative
(vDate date not null,
inQty decimal (12,2) not null default 0.0,
outQty decimal (12,2) not null default 0.0
);

insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-24',700.00,0.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-01',500.00,0.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-02',500.00,0.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-03',550.00,0.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-04',100.00,0.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-05',200.00,0.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-05',0.00,100.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-02',0.00,500.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-03',  0.00    ,150.0);
insert into dateCumulative values ('2011-10-24',  200.00  ,0.0);

select t.vDate,t.inQty,t.outQty,
round(t.inQtySum-t.outQtySum,2) as balance
from
( 
select 
(case when vDate = @curDate then (@inCsum := @inCsum + inQty) else @inCsum := inQty   end) as inQtySum,
(case when vDate = @curDate then (@outCsum := @outCsum + outQty) else @outCsum := outQty end) as outQtySum,
(case when vDate != @curDate then @curDate := vDate end) as dateChanged,
dc.*
from dateCumulative dc
inner join (SELECT @curDate := '1970-01-01',@inCsum:=0,@outCsum:=0) as t
order by vDate asc
) t;
```